# Center <UL> in <DIV>

Tags: html

I tried many solution from stackoverflow to center my `<UL>` with no success. Can anyone check it?

http://mihalko.eu/index.php

I want to center "Shop  943 01 ... not available".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a fixed width on the ul you can use `auto` as value for the horizontal margin to center the ul.

```
ul {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Width can't be auto for the ul?

Answer (score 5):

HTML :

```
<div class="div">
<ul>
<li>Test 1</li>
<li>Test 2</li>
<li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.div {
    text-align: center;
}
.div ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.div ul li {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```